# sql Tables manipulation

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image: tables]

Hi everyone,

i have the above table 'given table' i would like to create a new table with columns 'product', 'paid' , 'branchA' and 'branchB' as shown in the 'desired output table' with the unique identifier column 'id'. This must be a simple sql task, but here i am.  Any constructive suggestions  or code samples are welcome.
thx in advance

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Images of data are almost as useful as images of queries, but still they don't provide DDL. What have you tried? What research have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a number of ways to do this. Make sure that you fully understand whichever one you choose.

My approach is to union the first set of columns together with the second set.

```
SELECT *
INTO   new_table
FROM   (
           SELECT
                id
              , T_product AS [product]
              , T_paid    AS [paid]
              , T_branchA AS [branchA]
              , T_branchB AS [branchB]
           FROM given_table
           UNION
           SELECT
                id
              , S_product AS [product]
              , S_paid    AS [paid]
              , S_branch  AS [branchA]
              , S_branch2 AS [branchB]
           FROM given_table
       ) x;
```

Comment: `UNION ALL`, rather than `UNION`, would be more performant here, as then there is no implicit `DISTINCT` in the derived data set (which can be quite a costly operation).

Comment: @Larnu I'd also be concerned about reading the same table twice, completely unnecessary

Answer (score 4):

You need to **unpivot**, the easiest way to do this is `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  v.product,
  v.paid,
  v.branchA,
  v.branchB
-- INTO newTABLE  -- add this to insert into a new table
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      (t.T_product, t.T_paid, t.T_branchA, t.T_branchB),
      (t.S_product, t.S_paid, t.S_Branch, t.S_Branch2)
) v (product, paid, branchA, branchB);
```

Answer (score -2):

The general syntax for this would be:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, 
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition;
```

Therefore for your case it would be:

```
SELECT id, product, paid, branchA, branchB
INTO desired_output_table
FROM given_table;
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp